# Python Discord get_member() returns a value of None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Im using the following code to get a user thats in the server however it always returns a value of none. The bot has admin perms and we are spelling the users username correctly each time. I'm not including the numbers at the end even though I have tried that. Please can someone show me where I'm going wrong. Thanks

```
@client.command(name="getuser" ,pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
@commands.guild_only()
async def get_user(ctx):

    msg = ctx.message
    
    server = msg.guild

    await ctx.send(f"The @ of the user")

    def getUsername(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel 

    Key = await client.wait_for("message", check=getUsername)

    user_name = ctx.guild.get_member_named(name=str(Key.content))
    
    if not user_name:
        try:
            user_name = ctx.guild.get_member(int(Key.content))
            await ctx.send(f"Result: " + str(user_name))
        except:
            print("User Not Found")
    if not user_name:
        try: 
            user_name = self.bot.get_user(int(Key.content))
            await ctx.send(f"Result: " + str(user_name))
        except:
            print("User Not Found")
        
    if not user_name:
        await ctx.send(f'Could not find user.')
        
        

    print(f"Result: " + str(user_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_x` and `utils.get` both return `None` if they can't find anything matching.
Common causes include:

- Not subscribed to the relevant intent.
- Wrong key
- Bot not logged in, and trying to grab objects from cache
- Bot cannot "see" the object.
- Objects retuned by `fetch_x` will not have a populated cache.

Pretty sure you didn't enable `intents.members`, see: [Privileged Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?#privileged-intents)

*Also, those three `if-statements` are useless, you can put everything in one*

Comment: do you have discord or a way i can contact you i have another question. Thanks for the response im looking into the perms.

Comment: sent you a request :)